# Extending javascript libraries (underscore, jquery, backbone etc.)

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, javascript

I use multiple libraries in my code and want to extend them with custom functions.

I've looked around github, and understand the general logic to achieve that, but need some clarifications.

#### EXTENDING UNDERSCORE

```
(function() {

    _.mixin({

        // Custom methods

    });

}).call(this);
```

What does `(function(){  }).call(this);` stand for here?
Why do we need it?
Why is it between parentheses?
What exactly does `call(this);` do?

#### EXTENDING JQUERY

```
(function (factory) {
    if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory;
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {

    // Custom methods

}));
```

What is `function(factory)`? Why wasn't it used when extending underscore?
Why do we have `$` as an argument here in the second function, but we didn't use `_` with underscore?

#### EXTENDING BACKBONE

```
;(function(factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['underscore', 'backbone'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(_, Backbone);
    }
}(function(_, Backbone) {

    // Custom methods

    return Backbone;

}));
```

Why do we `return Backbone` at the end? Can I omit the `function(factory)` here and make a general `function(factory)` for all libraries I want to extend?

I'm confused by all this, if you have time to answer some of my questions that would be great!

Comment: Those patterns actually have few things to do with extending a library, only the `custom methods` part does. They can be found in many places, and are rather specific to the environment and module organisation used in a project, not to the library. Can you maybe include links for where exactly you found these snippets?

Answer (score 3):

**Underscore**

- What does (function(){  }).call(this); stand for here?
- Why do we need it?
- Why is it between parentheses?
- What exactly does call(this); do?

It's a self executing anonymous function.

It creates a private (function) scope, so any variables (var) are declared in it will not leak into a higher scope (probably window).

.call(this) just calls the function with the context of 'this' (current scope, probably window).

**Summary**

- Declares an anonymous function (not assigned to a variable)
- Then immediately executes/calls it with its context as this.